# How to interpred medflex mediation results?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, mediation

I have the following `dataset` of 108 samples:

```
Gender  Age severityBin MAS_Mediation outcome
     0   26 low         0             1
     1   54 high        1             0
     1   42 high        0             1
     0   35 low         1             1
     ..................................
```

I am trying to conclude whether the following mediation model can explain the data I have:

[image]

C is the set of confounders (`Gender` and `Age`)

A is the exposure (`severityBin`)

M is the mediator (`MAS_Mediation`)

Y is the outcome (`outcome`)

I did 2 things so far:

- Checked if there is any effect from exposure to the outcome:

  ```
  fit1TE <- glm(outcome ~ severityBin + Gender + Age, 
        data=dataset, family = "binomial")
  ```

  `summary(fit1TE)` returns:

  ```
  Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept)     1.620736   0.883986   1.833 0.066737 .  
  severityBinLow -2.235159   0.586276  -3.812 0.000138 ***
  Gender1        -0.311293   0.558813  -0.557 0.577486    
  Age             0.008285   0.019649   0.422 0.673280
  ```
- Performed mediation analysis using MAS_Mediation as the mediator

  ```
  library(medflex)
  fitImp <- glm(outcome ~ severityBin + (MAS_Mediation) + Age 
                + Gender, data=dataset, family = "binomial")
  expendedData <- neImpute(fitImp, nMed=1)
  fitNEM <- neModel(outcome ~ severityBin0 + severityBin1+ Age + 
     Gender, expData = expendedData, family = "binomial", se = "robust")
  ```

  `summary(fitNEM)` returns

  ```
  ---
  Exposure: severityBin  
  Mediator(s): MAS_Mediation 
  ---
  Parameter estimates:
                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept)      1.50247    0.94932   1.583 0.113496    
  severityBin0Low -1.16491    0.54400  -2.141 0.032242 *  
  severityBin1Low -1.07773    0.29955  -3.598 0.000321 ***
  Age              0.01180    0.02053   0.575 0.565559    
  Gender1         -0.32461    0.53195  -0.610 0.541713
  ```

  `summary(neEffdecomp(fitNEM))` returns:

  ```
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  natural direct effect    -1.1649     0.5440  -2.141 0.032242 *  
  natural indirect effect  -1.0777     0.2995  -3.598 0.000321 ***
  total effect             -2.2426     0.5863  -3.825 0.000131 ***
  ```

My question is: **how to conclude from these results** whether or not the outcome is influenced by the exposure through a mediator? Or do I need to do something more?

Answer (score 1):

The natural indirect effect represents the effect of the exposure that passes through the mediator. Given the small p-value I would say there is evidence for mediation. It appears that approximately half of the total effect of the exposure is mediated through the mediator. See [Nguyen, Schmid, & Stuart (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.08515) for an explanation on how to substantively interpret natural indirect and direct effects.